# How to assemble same elements in pandas.dataframe, python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which only has one index and two columns. But the number of rows can be very large (e.g. 1000). I want to assemble the same elements from different rows and columns. With the following codes, I elaborate my question.

```
import pandas as pd
data = dict()
data['id'] = ['r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6','r7','r8','r9','r10']
data['col1'] = [1,2,3,2,4,5,5,5,6,7]
data['col2'] = [2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('id')
```

Then, the content of `df` is shown below.

```
df = 

    col1    col2
id

r1     1       2
r2     2       3
r3     3       4
r4     2       4
r5     4       5
r6     5       6
r7     5       6
r8     5       6
r9     6       0
r10    7       0
```

For example, `df.loc['r1', 'col2']` and `df.loc['r2', 'col1'])` both have the number `2`. Based on this `df`, I want to generate the following dictionary:

```
dict_result[2] = ['r1_col2', 'r2_col1']
...
dict_result[4] = ['r3_col2', 'r4_col2', 'r5_col1']
...
dict_result[0] = ['r9_col2', 'r10_col2']
```

Could you please show me how to efficiently obtain such a `dict_result`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to melt, assign a new location column from the id and the column, and then use `groupby`:

```
melted = df.reset_index().melt("id").assign(loc=lambda x: x["id"] + "_" + x["variable"])
result = {k: v.tolist() for k, v in melted.groupby("value")["loc"]}
```

which gives me

```
In [546]: result
Out[546]: 
{0: ['r9_col2', 'r10_col2'],
 1: ['r1_col1'],
 2: ['r2_col1', 'r4_col1', 'r1_col2'],
 3: ['r3_col1', 'r2_col2'],
 4: ['r5_col1', 'r3_col2', 'r4_col2'],
 5: ['r6_col1', 'r7_col1', 'r8_col1', 'r5_col2'],
 6: ['r9_col1', 'r6_col2', 'r7_col2', 'r8_col2'],
 7: ['r10_col1']}
```